# Exception Production in os vista

Tags: c#, winforms

Why make an exception in the code is not :

```
try
{

FileIOPermission FIP = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, @"c:\SD.txt");


FIP.Demand();//Exception must rise here

StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(@"c:\SD.txt");//but Exception rise here
SW.Write(textBox1.Text);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

The following code should generate an exception in Windows Vista do

```
   FIP.Demand();//Exception must rise here
```

Why not create?

My OS : Vista

Comment: your question is not clear....

Comment: If UAC is enabled the operating system directs write access to files you don't have permission for to `$Env:LocalAppData\VirtualStore` (file and registry virtualization). Maybe you see that here.

Comment: You deleted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869419/the-code-does-not-work-on-windows-vista); now you're re-asking it here. Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: Sorry. This question is very important to me.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat,@ Joey:   I want to make exceptions. What should I do

Answer (score 0):

You are checking code execute permissions, not actual file permissions.

Comment: @ehsan_d18: First steps would be to research how they are different, once you understand that, it should be clear.